The Slidable component sometimes goes on top of other components and sometimes underneath - FLUTTER
Description:
I am encountering an issue with the Slidable component in a ListView in Flutter. The behavior of the Slidable component is inconsistent depending on the number of items in the list.
Problem:

When the ListView does not have enough items to require scrolling, the Slidable component appears on top of all other components when slid.
However, when the ListView has enough items to enable scrolling, the Slidable component goes underneath other components when slid.

Video of the problem:
Video
Code:
/* Events.dart */

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 10, right: 10),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.lista.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Slidable(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                  extentRatio: 0.2,
                  motion: const BehindMotion(),
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        delete(context, widget.lista[index]);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                              right: Radius.circular(15)),
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(widget.action(
                      fetchRep: widget.fetchRep,
                      data: widget.data,
                      update: widget.update,
                      action: "mod_el",
                      report: widget.lista[index]));
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6),
                  // margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 3, 10, 3),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
                    color: HexColor.fromHex(widget.lista[index].color),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            widget.lista[index].reportType == "R"
                                ? Icons.assignment
                                : Icons.bookmark,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "[  ${int.parse(widget.lista[index].quantity).toStringAsFixed(2)} ${widget.lista[index].unityCode}  ]",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "${widget.lista[index].customerCode} - ${widget.lista[index].taskTypeCode}",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

/* ContainerEvents.dart */ 

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
      child: AnimatedVisibility(
          enter: fadeIn(),
          exit: fadeOut(),
          child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiaryContainer,
              ),
              child: widget.loading
                  ? Center(
                      child: LoadingAnimationWidget.staggeredDotsWave(
                        color:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onTertiaryContainer,
                        size: 80,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                                "${DateFormat.EEEE('it_IT').format(widget.selezionato)}, ${DateFormat.MMMd('it_IT').format(widget.selezionato)}, ${DateFormat.y('it_IT').format(widget.selezionato)}",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Theme.of(context)
                                        .colorScheme
                                        .onTertiaryContainer,
                                    fontSize:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                                            100 *
                                            2.5,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)
                                      .colorScheme
                                      .inverseSurface,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  showModalBottomSheet(
                                    transitionAnimationController:
                                        AnimationController(
                                            vsync: Navigator.of(context),
                                            duration: const Duration(
                                                milliseconds: 600))
                                          ..forward(),
                                    context: context,
                                    isScrollControlled: true,
                                    builder: (context) => Filterbox(
                                        fetchRep: widget.fetchRep,
                                        data: widget.data,
                                        aggiornaData: widget.dayReload),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.filter_alt,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                                ))
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                          child: Events(
                              data: widget.selezionato,
                              lista: widget.lista,
                              action: widget.createRoute,
                              fetchRep: widget.fetchRep,
                              update: widget.update),
                        )),
                      ],
                    ))),
    );
  }

What I've Tried:

I have experimented with different Stack and Positioned configurations.

What I Want:

I want all the sliders to always be on top of other components.


I fixed the issue by modifying the Events.dart file. Here's what I added:
/* Events.dart */
class VerticalClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(-double.maxFinite, 0);
    path.lineTo(double.maxFinite, 0);
    path.lineTo(double.maxFinite, size.height);
    path.lineTo(-double.maxFinite, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

class _EventsState extends State<Events> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 10, right: 10),
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: VerticalClipper(),
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
          itemCount: widget.lista.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Stack(children: [
            // Your item builder logic here
            ...
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

The issue was that the Clip was creating a frame as large as the container, which prevented the slider from going beyond it. By doing this, the Clip will be as tall as the component it is in, while the width will be equivalent to that of the phone.
Solution provided by @Francesco Rasi
